# Postfix unable to send and receive emails

Tags: dns, email, postfix, mail, dovecot

I have a new ubuntu server, version 23.04, where I have Webmin installed and through which I installed Postfix and Dovecot. I have a local user (eml_user1) that I want to have the email address eml_user1@example1.com. Now, because of a constraint, I want to have another domain pointed to the same server, and on that to have eml_user2@example2.com. For now I'm working on the first user to get the emails working and I am stuck.

Not sure what information to provide, so I will try to provide as much and as relevant I can, but please ask for details if needed.

Domain is GoDaddy and host is Linode/Akamai with private IP. I made the following settings:
A @ {IP}, A imap (IP}, A mail {IP}, A mx {IP}, A pop {IP}, a smtp {IP}, MX @ mx.example1.com, MX * mx.example1.com

On server side I have a local user, eml_user1, member of groups "mail" and "postfix"

There was no file in /var/mail/eml_user1 as I couldn't receive any emails.

What am I missing?

Please keep in mind in your answers that I have to follow up with setup to set the second user on second domain on same server.

Thanks in advance!